# count > 0 mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

```
Class User
has_many :gifts
end

Class Gift
belongs_to :user
end
```

I want find if one or more users have one or more gifts something like:

```
User.any_of(gift: > 0).count
```

How is the correct query?

Thank you

Comment: perhaps you need to embed the gift in user model then it could work

Comment: Does something like this work `User.any_of(:gifts.exists => true)`

Comment: Thank you, If I run: `users = User.any_of(:gifts.exists => true).count` I get `0` however yes exists more gifts... However If I run `users = User.any_of(:gifts.exists => false).count` I get number > 0. I dont understand this query...

Comment: is gifts embedded in user document

Comment: See I gave you the suggest based upon the query since as far I know has_many model cannot be added to conditions straight forward you need to includes it first remember N+1 thing

Answer (score 0):

If Embed Document

```
User.any_of(:gifts.exists => true)
```

would work out of the blue

If not a Embed Document

Perhap I think you need to perform something like this

```
users_has_gifts = User.includes(:receivers).map { |user| 
  user if user.receivers.exits?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO only with map-reduce:

```
mapper = %{
function() { emit(this.user_id, 1) }
}

reducer = %{
function(k, vals) {
  var sum = 0;
  vals.forEach(function(val) {
    sum += val;
  });
return sum;
}
}

Gift.collection.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out: {inline: 1}, raw: true)
```

Then you can go over the result and pick the ones you like.
And if you have large collections, and you don't want them to be returned inline, then you can use out: {replace: 'collection_name'}, and then you can even chain selectors, like:
.where(value.gte => 2).limit(10)
I think that you can take it from here.